# My Laravel Auth::attempt() function not working

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

This is my controller

```
 if($request->isMethod('post')){
        $data = $request->input();
        if(Auth::attempt(['email'=>$data['username'],'password'=>$data['password'],'user_type'=>'2'])){                
            return redirect('/business/dashboard');
```

Comment: okay ... what is your question?

Comment: the condition is not checking.

Comment: how did you store the user you are trying to login as? do they have a field named `user_type` that is equal to `2`?

Comment: yes i have a user_type

Comment: how did you store this user? does `$data['username']` hold an email address? did you hash the password for them when you stored the user? does `user_type` equal `2`?

Comment: the user that has the credentials you are trying to use to login, do they have a `user_type` that is equal to `2`? how did you create this user in the database?

Comment: i have 3 different user. i first user as admin and customer are working properly. but only  for this user the condition doesn't working

Comment: You need to provide more information about the problem and how to ask your question. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code: if user_type column type is integer, give 2 without inverted Commas otherwise same code and password must be hash::make otherwise auth::attempt won't work.

```
     if($request->isMethod('post')){
     $user = User::where(['email'=>$request['username'],'user_type'=>'2'])->first();
    if(!empty($user)){
 if(Auth::attempt(['email'=>$request['username'],'password'=>$request['password']])){                
        return redirect('/business/dashboard');
    }
   abort(404);
```